# Need a scrolling (left to right) effect for a Chat Assistant Icon on the UI

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I am looking for a scrolling kind of effect for a Chat Assistant Icon which should work as follows:

1. The icon should initially be on right side of the window, (float:right and say some 10px from the top.)
2. When mouse hovers on it, the icon should expand as shown in the image.
3. When the mouse hovers out of the icon, it should retract back to it's initial position.
4. The position of the icon should be sticky/fixed even when the user scrolls up/down the page.
   I am attaching two screenshots which shows the position before the hover and on hover. Could you tell how to achieve it using HTML, CSS3 and JQuery(or native Java Script). Feel free to use any dummy image/text for demonstration purpose. Thanks.

[image: before hover]    [image: after hover]

Comment: We are always glad to help and support new coders but you need to help yourself first. After [doing more research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527), if you have a problem, please post what you've tried with a clear explanation of what isn't working and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read ['How to Ask a good question' guide](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [Question Do's and Don'ts](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527), and [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: Have u tried any code? or can i proceed my own code?

Comment: actually I had tried in various ways but couldn't get the CSS to match correctly with the requirement. Thank you Stack Overflow for the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add these code and plz change the image path..

**HTML**

```
<a href="#" class="back-top">
    <img src="icon.png" alt="">
    <h5>Virtual Assistant</h5>
</a>
```

**CSS**

```
.back-top {
    border: 1px solid #429dd8;
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    top: 10px;
    z-index: 9;
    border-right: none;
    padding: 10px;
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000;
}
.back-top img {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.back-top h5 {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-size: 0px;
    transition: 0.5s all ease 0s;
}
.back-top:hover h5 {
    font-size: 16px;
    transition: 0.5s all ease 0s;
}
```

Comment: thank you @Manikandan2811. I had tried from my end indeed but could not get the right css trick. Thank you once again for the solution!